# How to batch transfer rename?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

There are two folders holding equal amounts of files between them.
I'd like to apply the names from one set ; to the other set of files in no particular order. Inherit the name, but retain the extension .

Input files are .bmp Output files are .ini  ( has a gear symbol ).

Example :

```
 folder 1-  Flowers.bmp  ; folder 2- blank.ini
. To this:
 folder 1-  Flowers.bmp  ; folder 2- Flowers.ini
```

There would be more files , but equal  .
The .ini files are all copies .  So they may have a generic name and numbered   if that matters to know . Those would all receive one name each from the other .bmp files in the other folder.

Normally I have both folders situated on the Desktop .
I make sure both folders have equal number of files between them . That would be a constant .

I'm trying to stream line some menial repetitive daily tasks .
I did search and what I have found does not really help.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "vers=%~1"
IF "%vers%" == "" SET /P "vers=Enter Vers: "
FOR %%F IN (file_XX_*.*) DO CALL :process "%%F"
GOTO :EOF

:process
SET "name=%~nx1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "name=!name:_XX_=_%vers%_!"
RENAME %1 "%name%"
ENDLOCAL
```

Hoping to find a solution to this finally .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a slightly long version, but it makes sure it gets the content of each folder.

**Note** You must ensure that the path to both folders are correctly specified in the third and fourth line:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source=%userprofile%\Desktop\folder 1"
set "destination=%userprofile%\Desktop\folder 2"
set /a num=0
for %%a in ("%source%\*") do (
  set /a num+=1
  set "fr!num!m=%%~na"
)
set /a oldn=!num!
set /a num=0
for %%b in ("%destination%\*") do (
  set /a num+=1
  set "to!num!r!=%%~nxb"
  set "ext=%%~xb"
)
pushd "%destination%"
for /l %%i in (1,1,!oldn!) do ren "!to%%ir!" "!fr%%im!%ext%"
popd
pause
```

You can remove `pause` at the bottom of the script, once you are happy with the output.

Comment: oh wow. thanks man. that worked. i just made sure the folders said folder 1  and the other folder 2 . and it worked. im happy .

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most effective way, but considering your limited batch experience, I guess an understandable approach is better than an optimized one (using array-like variables).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for %%A in ("folder 1\*.bmp") do echo %%~nA)> "%temp%\names.txt"

<"%temp%\names.txt" (
for %%A in ("folder 2\*.ini") do (
  set /p "name="
  ECHO ren "%%A" "!name!.ini"
))
```

The first `for` loop creates a list of the desired names (from `Folder 1`). The modifier `%%~nA` returns the **n**ame only.

The second `for` processes each file in `Folder 2` and takes a name from the previously generated file for each file. *This depends on the fact that the number of files in both folders are the same*, else you may get undesired results.

I disabled the actual `ren` command by just echoing it. Check the output and only when you are satisfied, remove the `ECHO`.

Comment: Don't run it with Doubleclick for troubleshooting. Open a `cmd` window and run it from there, so you are able to see any errormessages.